# How to declutter your main.tex

Tags: formatting, packages, overleaf, document-classes

Is there a way to declutter your `LaTeX` project? Errors built up, but it is hard to find out which packages are unnecessary / clashing packages. Especially if you are working with a template and are customizing along the way:

```
\documentclass[
11pt,english, onehalfspacing, nolistspacing, liststotoc, headsepline, oneside, chapterinoneline, reqno, a4paper, toctotoc, table]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib=true, autocite=inline, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, exscale, latexsym, float, eucal, mathtools, adjustbox, textcomp, mathpazo, lipsum, rotating, pdflscape, subcaption, booktabs, makecell, flafter, xpatch, wrapfig, tikz, minted, arydshln, blkarray, tabularx, array}
%

%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDITIONAL FORMATTING
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=1cm, % Inner margin
    outer=1cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=0.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{width=0.8\textwidth}

\renewcommand{\chapterbelowskip}{\vspace{30pt}} % Spacing after chapter title
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\chapapp \thechapter\enskip}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} % In-text line spacing
\renewcommand{\chapterfont}{\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\roman{subfigure}}
\newcommand{\euler}{e}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}
\newcommand{\Corr}{\mathrm{Corr}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\plim}{plim}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\nint}\lfloor\rceil
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}\lvert\rvert

\makeatletter % Align list of figures and tables
 \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{2}{0em}{3.2em}}
 \renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{2}{0em}{3.2em}}
\makeatother

\expandafter\def\expandafter\normalsize\expandafter{%
    \normalsize
    \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0em}
    \setlength\belowdisplayskip{1em}
    \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0em}
    \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{1em}
}

\newcommand\crd{\cellcolor{red!25}}
\newcommand\cgr{\cellcolor{green!25}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth{\mylen}{VIII}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   REPORT INFORMATION
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}

\usemintedstyle{vs}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}

\input{Chapters/Titlepage}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\tableofcontents
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   CHAPTERS
%-------------------------------------------------------------

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{thesis}

\include{Chapters/Abstract}
\include{Chapters/Background}
\include{Chapters/Methods}
\include{Chapters/Results}
\include{Chapters/Discussion}
\include{Chapters/Conclusion}
\include{Chapters/Appendix}


%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   APPENDICES
%-------------------------------------------------------------

%\appendix
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
%\setcounter{figure}{0}

%-------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%-------------------------------------------------------------

%\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]

%----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

As you can see, a lot of packages and a lot of options added to `documentclass`. How can one declutter such a main.tex, removing any errors?

Comment: you should really avoid ever getting in to a situation where you need to ask this question. always start a document with an empty preamble and only add packages when you need a command from the package

Comment: There is no automatic way to “declutter” your .tex code. For that reason alone you
shouldn't blindly add packages to your source, or use templates “as is”,
i.e. without understanding (and probably customizing) the code.

My advice would be to pick a class you feel comfortable with, and start with
“Hello, world!” adding features that you actually need as you go along. If you don't know
 what `\usepackage{foobar}` does, there's a chance you don't need it: comment
 it out for the time being unless and until you have an actual need for it.

Also, redundant code is redundant.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should really avoid ever getting in to a situation where you need to ask this question. always start a document with an empty preamble and only add packages when you need a command from the package

However some comments on this particular example.

You load *loads* of packages but still get undefined command errors

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \usetikzlibrary 
                                
l.11 \usetikzlibrary
                    {calc}
```

Since that is not defined, it clearly is not used, so delete that line.

Similarly

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.21 \geometry
              {
?
```

so remove

```
\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=1cm, % Inner margin
    outer=1cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=0.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
```

as it is not doing anything other than generate an error. (If you loaded `geometry` earlier, so it was defined, it might be worse as 1cm margins on a single column A4 document would be painfully long lines to read.

You then get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \chapterbelowskip undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.33 \renewcommand{\chapterbelowskip}
                                     {\vspace{30pt}} % Spacing after chapter...

?
```

so again, these lines are doing nothinng but generate errors, so delete

The, if you run with `shell-escape` it runs without error but latex warns you

```
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [english,onehalfspacing,nolistspacing,liststotoc,headsepline,chapterinoneli
ne,toctotoc].
```

As almost all the options used are not defined (and `reqno` is the default) so just use

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
```

You then get the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\__hook_toplevel begindocument -> \hypersetup
```

so add

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

then yet another error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \ttitle
```

so delete Both (!!!) copies of

```
\AtBeginDocument{
\hypersetup{pdftitle=\ttitle} % Set the PDF's title to your title
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=\authorname} % Set the PDF's author to your name
\hypersetup{pdfkeywords=\keywordnames} % Set the PDF's keywords to your keywords
}
```

Your preamble will the finally load without errors but still warning about package load order:

```
Package fvextra Warning: csquotes should be loaded after fvextra, to avoid a wa
rning from the lineno package on input line 37.
```

More generally, avoid doing long lists like

```
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, exscale, latexsym, float, eucal, mathtools, adjustbox, textcomp, mathpazo, lipsum, rotating, pdflscape, subcaption, booktabs, makecell, flafter, xpatch, wrapfig, tikz, minted, arydshln, blkarray, tabularx, array}
```

as it obscures which packages you have loaded.

Some packages just define new commands so loading them and not using them just slows things down without real harm but you should delete if they are not used. eg `lipsum` should never appear in a real document, do you really use `blkarray`?? (I wrote it 25 years ago and have never used it in a real document)

Other packages affect the entire document just by loading them, it is clearer to separate these to individual `\usepackage` calls, for example in the middle of that list is `mathpazo` so you switch to a very old palatino font setup, probably `newpxtext,newpxmath` would be better these days.

`minted` is a fine package but forces `--shell-escape` so only load it if you are using it, and take care not to use untrusted code in that case. (This doesn't apply to overleaf which always uses shell-escape, and mitigates the risk using docker containers and by being a hosted service not on your machine)

Comment: Absolutely amazing answer, impressed by your LaTeX level. The document looks 100-fold better. Since I am using a template, packages such as hyperref are loaded in the .cls-file.

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research I suspected as much but means you made your question rather unrelated to your real document. Your example used report so almost all the options and code lines used were undefined. if your question had used a different class that defines them, the answer (apart from the first paragraph) would have been different.

Comment: `\begin{joke}`
Correction: `lipsum` should be used in *every single* LaTeX document. Always. Especially if you have to write 2000-word essay and only have 700 words.
`\end{joke}`

Answer (score 3):

As you ask for a `systematic process`, you could do it like this. I often apply it, when I added too much to my code in one go, or try understanding other peoples approaches. It's to some degree the inverse or the return to the step-by-step adding, as also mentioned in the two comments above.

**Process**:

- work on a copy of your original file(s)
- delete and/or comment out at least "half" of it, in your case almost all of it
- compile and correct as needed
- add more (strategically) once it compiles

**Example**:

- I deleted almost anything
- left only, what might be working (but still could be a bit too much)
- I strategically commented out what I'm trying next

Now, if file Titlepage (?) has some problems, repeat this process on a copy as well, until it works.

As a side-effect, indenting becomes somewhat natural with these few lines of code, which might result in a better outcome of your long code.

BTW, in terms of refactoring, see below, don't forget to consider moving certain parts to further files again. All those definitions and packages might be a subject for this. Pay attention to the difference between using `\input` and `\include` .

The **resulting code** will differ, whether I do it, or you do it, or somebody else does it. However, from observations all the benefits I described here will come to life easily. E.g. unwanted interaction amongst packages will show up with the next small step of added code, and will be much easier to spot, track down and manage.

```
    \documentclass{report}
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    
    %\usemintedstyle{vs}
    
    \begin{document}
    
        %\frontmatter
        %\pagestyle{plain}
    
        \input{Chapters/Titlepage}
    
    %-------------------------------------------------------------
    %   LIST OF CONTENTS/FIGURES/TABLES PAGES
    %-------------------------------------------------------------
        \tableofcontents
    
    %-------------------------------------------------------------
    %   CHAPTERS
    %-------------------------------------------------------------
    %   \mainmatter
    %   \pagestyle{thesis}
    
    \end{document}
```

**In perspective**, this follows the well known, well proven and highly recommended TDD (Test Driven Design) approach, which goes like this:

- define a test, which has to fail (`RED`, missing implementation)
- add, what's needed to pass (`GREEN`, just please the test(s))
- `REFACTOR` (deal with duplicates, prepare next small step etc.)
- `REPEAT` by defining the next test, which has to fail (nothing implemented, yet)

This results quickly in what I tend to call beauty-code: capable, with some kind of elegance, much easier to mantain, change, expand.

Now, `tests` here are: a) it compiles without (significant) errors, b) the text appears the way I want or at least good enough for now.

**Addendum**: Some ways to "`delete`" parts of your code.

1. always work on a file copy
2. physically delete lines of code
3. use your editors functions, i.e. mark (left mouse button down), cut (Ctrl+X) and undo (Ctrl+Z)
4. use `%` to comment out dedicated lines of code
5. use the conditional environments provided by package `comment` https://ctan.org/pkg/comment
6. use the `ifthen` package https://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen
7. see also related packages under topic "`condtional compilation`" https://ctan.org/topic/cond-comp
8. use the Tex primitive `\iffalse`
9. mark code snippets, cut and move them to dedicated new files, which you `\input` ; you can cascade other `\input` statements in said new files, i.e. repeat these steps
10. a combination of the approaches above

**Some characteristics** of these approaches:

1. fail-safe approach
2. visual clean-up, literally
3. can be a quick smart approach
4. easy to do, ends up being ugly many times

5-8. allows for optional "deletes" at the cost of more clutter

9. creates a hierarchical file-tree towards the errors
10. flexibility

Comment: To be fair we already have [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that? - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) which... will in most cases results in having the problem solved.

Comment: Ok, let's apply both strategies on several non-obvious codes posted here and compare.

Answer (score 3):

You can move many of the packages—especially those that are cosmetic, and would need to be replaced if you published in a journal with a different house style—into a `.sty` file.  If a command would still be needed within the document even if you changed its fonts and layout, I would recommend leaving it in the main document.

If you’re allowed to use it, a package such as `fontsetup` or `unicode-math` can replace a large number of font and symbol packages in your preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am curious, could you indicate which packages can be removed and replaced by these two?

Comment: @Sean_TBI_Research You need only one or the other. Generally, `fontenc` (since they load TU), `inputenc` (since they run on Unicode engines that don’t need it), any font package, any symbol package (including, in your example, `amssymb`, `latexsym`, `amsfonts` and `eucal`), and some miscellaneous packages it already loads for you (such as `amsmath`, also loaded by `mathtools`).