# How to remove excessive space between figures/formula and text?

Tags: floats, vertical-spacing

The space is more than normal. The figures are the same, more space than normal.

```
\documentclass[b5paper, 11pt, openany, titlepage]{book}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{tmargin=3.6cm, bmargin=3.6cm, lmargin=3.2cm, rmargin=3.2cm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}


\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter[]{Experimental and grating sensors}

\textbf{jimmy GHFARD}

\newpage

    \tableofcontents

    \listoffigures
    
    \newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introduction}

For both numerical and experimental inve using the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \varepsilon_{c}=\frac{\lambda_{k}-\lambda_{m}}{(1-\rho_{\varepsilon})  \lambda_{B}} 
    \label{eq:c_strain}
\end{equation} 
where indexes \textit{m} and \textit{B} are related to measured and base Bragg wavelengths, respectively. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `\linespread{1.5}`, it not to increase the spacing between lines?

Comment: Because this short code is already overloaded with packages not needed here, assuming the code still contains your problem, it might be a good chance to apply this systematic strategy to isolate the real problems: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159

Comment: @Mico yes between lines. Just lines!

Comment: @ David Carlisle where is mathit?

Comment: unrelated but do not use `\textit{m}` for math variables it is the wrong font use `$m$`

Comment: Sorry I reposted the comment without the typo. But have you checked the posted example does demonstrate your problem? I would have expected this was a faq about `book` using `\flushbottom` with an answer being to use `\raggdbottom` but this example doesn't really show that

Comment: What happens if you replace `\linespread{1.5}` with `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5} \raggedbottom`?

Comment: @Mico perfect! Thanks. Post it in answer I think