# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package

Tags: errors, packages

I'm writing my bachelor thesis with latex and I'm almost done, but now suddenly an error message is displayed with the packages, although I haven't changed anything. I already researched in which order the packages have to be listed, but there seems to be no universal rule. I would be very grateful if someone could find the error.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{equation}{chapter}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` before documentclass.

Comment: Welcome. // To isolate the trouble makers I suggest to try this systematic process on at least one copy of your work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159 . A good starting point might be the preamble to note down, which other parts of your thesis are or aren't affected (i.e. switching half of them on and off, so to say; see the process).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks, now there is no option clash with the packages anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your log shows

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2020/10/14 v3.0a eso-pic (RN)
\ESO@tempdima=\dimen144
\ESO@tempdimb=\dimen145

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 227.
```

so pdfpages loads `eso-pic` which loads `xcolor` with no option, so move

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

before

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

so it is already loaded.