# Empty bibliography on input line

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using latex with neovim and vimtex.
In the past, I've printed a bibliography successfully, albeit only a test version so to speak.
Now I have a "major" bibfile with around 30 entries.
In addition I've installed the 'unified style sheet for linguistics' and put it in my preamble.
I've tried some things but I get the said 'error'.

---

any help appreciated

the bib file is here:
https://justpaste.it/1wnye
the log file is here:
https://justpaste.it/6wbh2

the tex file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
             backend=biber,
             style=unified,
            ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{identity.bib}
\title{Bibliographie zu Identität und Gender im Rahmen der Diskurslinguistik}
\author{x} 
\date{ }


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle


    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use even `\nocite{*}` inside the `document` environment ... or cite one by one the "keys" of your entries in text (via command `\cite{<KeyHere>}`). In other case it will not find entries to add in the references section. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: A suggestion. Asking myself, why the bibliography should be correct, i.e. without typos or other problems, I‘d apply this strategy on a copy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159 . If your bib file should contain problems, you‘ll find them quickly this way (exponentially, more or less).

Comment: have you run biber to generate the bibliography? show the biber log (`.blg`)

Comment: sorry, wasn't aware; the blg. file:  https://justpaste.it/4fo41

Comment: @MS-SPO : thanks for the tip! looks like a good scheme to learn from!!

Comment: SOLVED! 

it was the \nocite{*} really.

happy now ...

Comment: Great! Can you please post a short answer, which shows the solution? A code snippet might do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\nocite` did the trick, as suggested.
...

```
\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
\nocite{*}

    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```