# Error with report class

Tags: report, documentclass

I am using the following packages for writing a document

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{import}
%\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1.25cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2.5cm, outer=2.5cm, top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm, bindingoffset=1.25cm, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcase}
% Load the package with the acronym option
%\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
%\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossariX}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\makegapedcells
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{tabto}
%\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}

\pagestyle{fancy}           % Sets fancy header and footer
```

This is the error I am getting:

> standalone.sty line 555 Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }

Comment: How can this code snippet compile??

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, I thought If an error is in the second line only. This could be enough, That's a huge file and confidential too. What to do?

Comment: If I make your code snippet compilable by (a) commenting out the instruction `\usepackage{glossariX}` and (b) appending the code snippet `\begin{document} Hello World. \end{document}`, I get no errors and or warning messages. Please do tell us more about the mysterious file `glossariX.sty`. E.g., is it available online? If not, what is in the file? Does your document even need this file?

Comment: Incidentally, the sequence of instructions `\usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage{kpfonts} \usepackage{mathptmx}` is absurd. You begin by loading the `lmodern` text and math font package, then you clobber `lmodern` with the `kpfonts` text and math font package, and then you clobber `kpfonts` with the borderline-obsolete `mathptmx` text and math font package. Please do go through your preamble and remove the deadwood.

Comment: A separate issue: Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated?

Comment: why do you load array multicol hyperref,... twice? start by removing all packages and then just add the ones you use in the document

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN - What to do? Build your code slowly, from few lines to many, from compile to compile. This way you can spot trouble early, e.g. the incomplete structure you posted - it can't compile, no matter how many packages you include. // Your code posted here should always be reduced. If it's too big, you may want to localize your problem(s) first, e.g. this way: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 , and then come up with a dedicated short version, which we can copy & compile .

Comment: @Mico, I tried removing this package, but the error message remains the same. @ all others, This is a latex template. The file is working fine with the sender, but with me, it's throwing the above error. I don't know where there is extra } . Cant upload the whole thesis here.

Comment: @Mico I am using TeXstudio 3.1.1

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks I will do the same and update here.

Comment: Finally, I got it. My question is wrong here I thought its a package importing error, so put this much code only. Will see what best I can ask to resolve this issue. The same file is working with someone else but not with my editor.

Comment: @KRISHNACHAUHAN - TeXstudio is merely a front end to a TeX distribution, but not the TeX distribution itself. Let me repeat my question: "Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when was it last updated?"

Comment: Okay, sir, I am using MiKTeX; the last updation I am unaware of; I am using it for last year. As I said, it's a thesis template, so it includes many .tex files for each chapter and front pages. I am getting a curly bracket error ( } ), But I can't find it.