# Compilation error while compiling the thesis main file

Tags: chapters, thesis

I am trying to compile the main file of the thesis, which uses \include to add each chapter. I got this following error (The error said that it is related to the .toc file).

Would any one kindly direct me to what went wrong?
Also, I am quite sure there was no missing \item.
I can share any file if needed.

Thanks very much

------------------------------ beginning of error message -------------

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.4 \contentsline
{chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}

------------------------------ End of error message -------------

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: Welcome. // To localize your error(s), I suggest following a systematic process as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 . Basically you chop all your code down into pieces, which do compile and those, which don't. Next you repeat until you can have a closer look into the "don't" portions of code.

Comment: Quite often this kind of error come from `.toc` or `.aux` files which work in a specific situation and not ior he whole document. As a first resort, have you tried to delete all the generated files (except the drawibgs if any) to perform a "fresh" compilation ? As other commetators wrote, without code we can't help furtherand stripping down  your code would be helpfull, either for findlng by your self the origin of the problem  or for us if you can post some shorter code than the whole thesis.