# How to create captioned TikZ pictures inside a tblr?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, positioning, tabularray

I'd like to position two TikZ pictures side by side, with the captions "Before" and "After", respectively. How can I do this?

I tried placing the TikZ pictures inside `figure` environments, for the captions, and placing the `figure` environments inside a `tblr`, for the positioning, as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{float}%For the 'H' option
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (1);
\caption{Before}
\end{figure}
&
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\caption{After}
\end{figure}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this code fails to compile in Overleaf with the 2022 LuaLaTeX compiler.

How can I fix the code to achieve the objective stated in the beginning of this post?

Comment: You probably have seen this approach to narrow down the problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 .

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that images can be arbitrary, so beside of `tikzpicture` I also use ˙example-image-duck`, which is available to anyone:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % for "valign",  also load graphicx
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter, varwidth}       % <===

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},
             measure = vbox     % <----
             }
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{Before.}   
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{After.}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c]},
             measure = vbox
             }
\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (1);
    \caption{Before.}
    &
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \caption{After.}
\end{tblr}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Note:**

- floats should not be inserted inside any box/table cell
- for inserting `\caption` in cells you need to load library `varwidth` and add to table preamble option `measure = vbox`
- that numbering of figure are correct, the library `counter` is needed

Answer (score 1):

If the captions' sole purpose is to attach to the pictures a brief description, and you don't need labels and figure tables, etc., you could add the captions in another row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{cells={halign=c}}
\tikz \draw (0,0) circle (1);
&
\tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\\
Before
&
After
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: Captions for TikZ pictures inside a tblr]

Comment: Is this an answer? It not solve any of problems reported in your question. If yes, than your question is very misleading!