# Package algorithmicx Error: Some stored algorithms are not restored!

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algpseudocode

I am using these two package: `\usepackage{algorithm}` and `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`.
This is my latex code and I am using overleaf:

```
   \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}
\title{algorithm_debug}
\author{author }
\date{June 2023}

\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicbreak}{\textbf{break}}
\newcommand{\BREAK}{\STATE \algorithmicbreak}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{labelformat=empty} %remove default caption
\newcounter{phase}[algorithm]
\newlength{\phaserulewidth}
\newcommand{\phaseTitle}{Phase} % <-- Enter default "phase name" here
\newcommand{\setphaserulewidth}{\setlength{\phaserulewidth}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{%
  \vspace{-1.25ex}
  % Top phase rule
  \Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}
  \Statex\strut\refstepcounter{phase}\item[\textbf{\phaseTitle~\thephase:~}\textit{~#1}] % phase "caption"
  % Bottom phase rule
  \vspace{-1.25ex}\Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}}

some  text
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \renewcommand\thealgorithm{}
    \caption{My Algorithm} 
    \begin{algorithmic}
      \setcounter{phase}{2}
      \phase{Computation}
            \State \textbf{Input :} meas $=$ errors in dictionary format
        \State \textbf{Output :}  RESULT   
            \State AII $=$ defaultdict(complex) 
            \For{nameH, valueH in A.items()}:
               \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
                  \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
                     \State name = (*nameH *nameI *nameI)
                     \State AII[name] = valueA *valueI *valueI
                   \EndFor
               \EndFor
            \EndFor  
            \State BI $=$ defaultdict(complex)
            \For{nameB, valueB in B.items()}:
               \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
                   \State name = (*nameB *nameI)
                   \State BI[name] = valueB *valueI 
               \EndFor
            \EndFor
            \State IC $=$ defaultdict(complex)
            \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
              \For{nameC, valuec in c.items()}:
                   \State name = ( *nameI *nameC)
                   \State IC[name] =  valueI * valuec
               \EndFor
            \EndFor
            \algstore{bkbreak}
            \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm}
           \begin{algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \State mII $=$ defaultdict(complex) 
            \For{nameM, valueM in m.items()}:
               \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
                  \For{nameI, valueI in I.items()}:
                     \State name = (*nameM *nameI *nameI)
                     \State measII[name] = valueM *valueI *valueI
                   \EndFor
               \EndFor
            \EndFor  
            \State RESULT $=$ sum(AII[k]*BII[k]*IC[k]*AII[k]*mII[k] \textbf{for} k \textbf{in} AII)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

I am having the following error: `Package algorithmicx Error: Some stored algorithms are not restored!.` I have no idea where is this error coming from. Is there any trick/way to skip this error?
Thank you!

Comment: well my algorithm to debug such problems need as input a complete minimal example.

Comment: I actually gave the minimal example

Comment: no you gave some snippets, that is not complete. I can't run and test it.

Comment: I have updated my example. I have checked and when you run it, you will have the same error. I am guessing the reason I am getting this error is because I am splitting my algorithm since it is too long. But I have to split it. I do not know how can I skip this errors

Comment: copy your example **unchanged**  in a new, **empty** test.tex.  Then compile it and tell me if the first error you get is the error you are asking about.

Comment: In the question, I gave my latex file completely. When I run this latex file in an empty project, I got 2 errors: ```1)  Undefined control sequence 2) Some stored algorithms are not stored``` I have updated the question for by including my whole latex file

Comment: we are getting nearer. Now correct the unrelated error because \text is not defined.

Comment: Though debugging external code is kind of fun sometimes, here‘s a procedure to localize your problem yourself: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 .

Comment: I have updated again and remove the ```\text```. We now have just one error

Comment: you are storing with `\algstore{bkbreak}` but don't restore. See the documentation how this should be done correctly (or remove the store command).

Comment: when I add ```\algrestore{bkbreak}```, it worked !!! However, I lost the line numbers... anyway, I will find a way

Comment: I found: If I want to print the numbers, I should use ```\algorithmic[1]``` and then instead of saying bkbreak, I should give a name like ```\algstore{part1} ..... \algrestore{part1}```