# Using \pdfsavepos in a discretionary

Tags: pdfsavepos

`\pdfsavepos` allows to find the current position. I need the position at the end of the last character in a line to place objects like a box at this position. My algorithm works fine at breakpoints like glue or space but I have no idea how to find the position after a hyphen. Is there any idea how to do this?

I reduced the code with respect to my question. The positions of the blanks will be written to a file named `<jobname.co>`. The position information will be anaylised at the end of the document and the rules drawn in the next run.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[main=english]{babel}%

\makeatletter

%

\newwrite\RJ@WriteCO%

\immediate\openout\RJ@WriteCO=\jobname.co\relax% 
open the co-file

%

\newif\ifRJ@COstarted%

%

\newenvironment{CrossOut}% delimitation of the 
region for crossing out 

 {%

  \ifvmode% output the position only in hmode

   \everypar\expandafter{\expandafter\everypar
\expandafter{\the\everypar}\the\everypar
\@CrossOut}%

   \global\let\next\relax%

  \else%

   \global\let\next\@CrossOut%

  \fi%

  \next%

 }%

 {%

  \ifRJ@COstarted% test if \CrossOut was started

   \nobreak\pdfsavepos%

   \write\RJ@WriteCO% write the end position of the 
region to the co file
{\noexpand\RJ@NewPageCO{\thepage}\noexpand
\RJ@EndPosCO%
{\the\pdflastxpos}%
{\the\pdflastypos}%
}%

  \fi%  

  \global\RJ@COstartedfalse%

 }%

%

% To avoid grouping conflicts with environments, 
the ending and new beginning

% of \CrossOut will not be done inside a group   

%   

\gdef\@CrossOut%

 {%

  \catcode`\ =13% make the blank active

  \RJ@DefBlankCO% define blanks

  \global\RJ@COstartedtrue%

  \pdfsavepos% write the starting position

  \write\RJ@WriteCO%
{\noexpand\RJ@NewPageCO{\thepage}%
 \noexpand\RJ@StartPosCO%
 {\the\pdflastxpos}{\the\pdflastypos}%
}%

 }%  



%

% Save the position of the blank

%

\def\RJ@Space{ }%

% 

{\catcode`\ =13\relax\gdef\RJ@DefBlankCO{\def 
{\RJ@SpaceCO}}}%

% 

\def\RJ@SpaceCO%

 {%

% save the current position

  \nobreak\pdfsavepos% current cursor position (baseline)

  \write\RJ@WriteCO{\the\pdflastxpos,
\the\pdflastypos}%

  \RJ@Space%

 }%


\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{4,5cm}%

this \begin{CrossOut}%

is an example for cross out text. this is an example for cross out text 
verylongwordveryyylongword. this is an example for cross out%

\end{CrossOut} text.

\end{minipage}

\hspace{2cm}

\begin{minipage}{4,5cm}\raggedright%

this \begin{CrossOut}%

this is an example for cross out text. this is an example for cross out textverylongwordveryyylongword. this is an example for cross out%

\end{CrossOut} text.

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

**Commented data in the co-file:**

```
% first minipage

\RJ@NewPageCO {1}\RJ@StartPosCO {9702016}
{46363020}% start the cross out 

10219654,46363020

11566630,46363020

14860095,46363020

16314021,46363020% position of the last blank in the first line equals eol

9557158,45412748

11322641,45412748

13537314,45412748

16314021,45412748% position of the last blank in the second line equals eol

8440600,44462476

9690251,44462476

12886393,44462476

14242994,44462476

16314021,44462476% position of the last blank in 
the third line equals eol

9035242,43512204

10974127,43512204% position of the last blank in the middle of the forth line. use eol.

13441582,42561932

15411957,42561932

16314021,425619326% position of the last blank in the fifth line equals eol

8735782,41611660

11783263,41611660

12991204,41611660

14913570,416116606% position of the last blank in the sixth line equals eol

\RJ@NewPageCO {1}\RJ@EndPosCO {16314021}{41611660}% and end of region

% second minipage

\RJ@NewPageCO {1}\RJ@StartPosCO {22058318}
{46363020} start the cross out

23303216,46363020

24077534,46363020

25147034,46363020

28163024,46363020 position of the last blank in the first line. right visible margin of this line.

21476510,45412748

23367386,45412748

24736346,45412748

26554496,45412748

28141634,45412748

28915952,45412748% position of the last blank in 
the second line after the last chracter

21369560,44462476

24385550,44462476

25562000,44462476

27452876,44462476

28821836,44462476% position of the last blank in 
the third line after the last chracter

21904310,43512204% position of the last blank in 
the middle of the forth line. use eol.

26075360,42561932

27662498,42561932

28436816,42561932% position of the last blank in the fifth line after the last chracter

21369560,41611660

24385550,41611660

25562000,41611660

27452876,41611660% position of the last blank in the sixth line after the last chracter

\RJ@NewPageCO {1}\RJ@EndPosCO {28821836}{41611660} end of region
```

**PDF**

[image]

If there is no last position in the code, I use the eol. It works fine in justified text but not in unjustified. This you can see in the PDF.

Comment: your question is not very clear and you provided no example. Normally the position of the end of line does not depend on the final character on the line so why does it matter whether that is `-` ? you can use `\pdfsavepos` anywhere on the line to get the y position and the x position is the right margin which you know in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the text is justified, the end of a line is identical with the position of the last character but otherwise the positions are different. Linebreak's can occur at blank's or \hskip's or kern's but also between a word. If you write \pdfsavepos before every potentially linebreak position, its possible to get the position of the end of the last object in a line. But I have no idea hoe to do that between a word speak at a discretionary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the text is justified, the end of a line is identical with the position of the last character but otherwise the positions are different. Linebreak's can occur at blank's or \hskip's or kern's but also between a word. If you write \pdfsavepos before every potentially linebreak position, its possible to get the position of the end of the last object in a line. But I have no idea hoe to do that between a word speak at a discretionary.

Comment: Sorry, I want to send a pdf, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: you can show a small complete test document an an image of the output where you can mark where you want the pdfsavepos. But you are asking about pdfsavepos at a hyphenation point, are they not always at the right margin?

Comment: Dear David, you will now find an example in the question block. The code is a little bit complex, but in principle the blanks are active and the associated command  is defined like 

\pdfsavepos\write\afile{\the\pdflastxpos,\the\pdflastypos}\space

But I have no idea how to append the \pdfsavepos at the end of a hyphen.

Thank you for your interest.

Reinhard

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome. // We love to read code here. If it's too complex, simplify while preserving your problem. For a systematic process to prune your code please have a look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790.