# Fatal error, no output pdf file

Tags: errors

I'm having a problem with building my `LaTeX` project. It occured suddenly and I don't know why. I undid the changes I did before, but it's still coming up.

I'm not sure what part of the code needs to be send. I know the preamble got a bit confusing, but maybe somebody can understand the problem?

The log says:

```
 [{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/D.Ertel/Desktop/Studium/BSC/Abschlussarbeit/preambel.tex",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": " ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!\nTranscript written on preambel.log.\nLatexmk: Getting log file 'preambel.log'\nLatexmk: Examining 'preambel.fls'\nLatexmk: Examining 'preambel.log'\nLatexmk: Index file 'preambel.idx' was written\nLatexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets\nCollected error summary (may duplicate other messages):\n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
```

---

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on preambel.log.
Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (850,65001)
Latexmk: Getting log file 'preambel.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'preambel.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'preambel.log'
Latexmk: Index file 'preambel.idx' was written
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: Command for 'pdflatex' gave return code 1
      Refer to 'preambel.log' and/or above output for details
```

thesis.tex:

```
\newcommand{\hsmasprache}{de} % de oder en für Deutsch oder Englisch

% Preambel mit Einstellungen importieren
\input{preambel.tex}

% Dokumenteninfos importieren
\input{docinfo.tex}

% Literatur-Datenbank
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}   % BibLaTeX-Datei mit Literaturquellen einbinden
\bibliography{literatur}


% Anfang des Dokuments
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% Römische Ziffern für die "Front-Matter"
\setcounter{page}{0}
\changefont{phv}{m}{n}  % Helvetica für den Fließtext
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}

% Titelblatt
\input{titelblatt}

% Inhaltsverzeichnis erzeugen
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

% Korrigiert Nummerierung bei mehrseitigem Inhaltsverzeichnis
\cleardoublepage
\newcounter{frontmatterpage}
\setcounter{frontmatterpage}{\value{page}}

% Arabische Zahlen für den Hauptteil
\mainmatter

% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
%\addchap{\hsmaabbreviations}
%\input{kapitel/abkuerzungen}
%\glsaddall
%\input{versuch.tex}
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
\setglossarystyle{alttree}
\printglossary[title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, toctitle=Abkürzungsverzeichnis, type=\acronymtype, nogroupskip]
\glsaddall[types=symbolslist]
\glsaddall[types=formel]
\glsaddall[types=lformel]
\printglossary[title= Lateinische Formelzeichen, toctitle=Lateinische Formelzeichen, type=lformel,style=mytab, nogroupskip]

\printglossary[title= Griechische Formelzeichen, toctitle=Griechische Formelzeichen, type=formel,style=mytab, nogroupskip]

\printglossary[title=Formelzeichen, toctitle=Formelzeichen, type=symbolslist, nogroupskip]


%\printglossary[type=symbolslist]
%\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
%\makeglossaries



% Den Hauptteil mit vergrößertem Zeilenabstand setzen
\onehalfspacing

% ------------------------------------------------------------------
% Hauptteil der Arbeit
%\input{kapitel/kapitel1} % Externe Datei einbinden
%\input{kapitel/kapitel2}
%\input{kapitel/kapitel3}
%\input{kapitel/kapitel4}
%\input{kapitel/kapitel5}
%\input{kapitel/kapitel6}



% ------------------------------------------------------------------

\label{lastpage}

% Neue Seite
\cleardoublepage

% Backmatter mit normalem Zeilenabstand setzen
\singlespacing

% Römische Ziffern für die "Back-Matter", fortlaufend mit "Front-Matter"
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{\value{frontmatterpage}}



% Tabellenverzeichnis erzeugen
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistoftables}
\listoftables

% Abbildungsverzeichnis erzeugen
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistoffigures}
\listoffigures

% Listingverzeichnis erzeugen. Wenn Sie keine Listings haben,
% entfernen Sie einfach diesen Teil.
% \cleardoublepage
% \phantomsection
% \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmalistings}
% \lstlistoflistings

% Literaturverzeichnis erzeugen
\begingroup
\cleardoublepage
\begin{flushleft}
    \let\clearpage\relax % Fix für leere Seiten (issue #25)
    \printbibliography
\end{flushleft}
\endgroup

% Index ausgeben. Wenn Sie keinen Index haben, entfernen Sie einfach
% diesen Teil. Die meisten Abschlussarbeiten haben *keinen* Index.
%\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hsmaindex}
%\printindex

% Anhang. Wenn Sie keinen Anhang haben, entfernen Sie einfach
% diesen Teil.
%\appendix
%\input{kapitel/anhang-a}
%\input{kapitel/anhang-b}

\end{document}
```

preambel.tex:

```
% Dokumententyp und benutzte Pakete
\documentclass[open=right,  % Kapitel darf nur auf rechten Seite beginnen
    paper=a4,               % DIN-A4-Papier
    fontsize=12pt,          % Schriftgöße
    headings=small,         % Kleine Überschriften
    headsepline=true,       % Trennlinie am Kopf der Seite
    footsepline=false,      % Keine Trennlinie am Fuß der Seite
    bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis aufnehmen
    twoside=off,             % Doppelseitiger Druck - auf off stellen für einseitig
    DIV=7,                  % Verhältnis der Ränder zum bedruckten Bereich
    chapterprefix=true,     % Kapitel x vor dem Kapitelnamen
    cleardoublepage=plain]{scrbook}


% Pakete einbinden, die benötigt werden
\usepackage{ifthen}               % Logische Bedingungen mit ifthenelse
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}     % Erweiterte Einstellungen an scrbook zulassen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % Dateien in UTF-8 benutzen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}          % Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage{graphicx}             % Bilder einbinden
\usepackage{enumitem}             % Eigene Listen definieren können
\usepackage{setspace}             % Abstände korrigieren
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{float}

% Setzen von Optionen abhängig von der gewählten Sprache. Die Sprache wird
% in thesis.tex gesetzt.
\ifthenelse{\equal{\hsmasprache}{de}} %
  {%
   \usepackage[main=ngerman, english]{babel}  % Deutsche Sprachunterstützung
   \addto\captionsngerman{%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Inhalt}
    }
   \usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes} % Deutsche Anführungszeichen
   \usepackage[pagebackref=false,german]{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
   \newcommand{\hsmasortlocale}{de_DE} % Sortierung der Literatur
  }%
  {%
   \usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel} % Englische Sprachunterstützung
   \usepackage[autostyle=true,english=american]{csquotes} % Englische Anführungszeichen
   \usepackage[pagebackref=false,english]{hyperref}  % Hyperlinks
   \newcommand{\hsmasortlocale}{en_US} % Sortierung der Literatur
  }%

\usepackage{xcolor}               % Unterstützung für Farben
\usepackage{amsmath}              % Mathematische Formeln
\usepackage{amsfonts}             % Mathematische Zeichensätze
\usepackage{amssymb}              % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{float}                % Fließende Objekte (Tabellen, Grafiken etc.)
\usepackage{booktabs}             % Korrekter Tabellensatz
%\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  % Abkürzungsverzeichnis [nur verwendete Abkürzungen]
\usepackage[automake,toc,acronym,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolverzeichnis}
\newglossary[fog]{formel}{foi}{foo}{Griechische Buchstaben}
\newglossary[flg]{lformel}{fli}{flo}{Lateinische Buchstaben}
\newglossarystyle{mytab}{%
 % Verzeichnis wird ein 'longtable'  mit 5 Spalten
% (rais) von denen Du nur 4 nutzt...
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
  {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}ccp{\glsdescwidth}p{\glspagelistwidth}@{}}}% (rais) ...entsprechend hab ich das hier auf 4 Spalten gekürzt.
  {\end{longtable}}%  
 % Kopf der Tabelle
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{% (rais) nun dann doch
  \bfseries Symbol & \bfseries Einheit & \bfseries Beschreibung\tabularnewline
  \endhead
}
 % Kein Abstand zwischen Gruppen
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
 \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
   \glsentryitem{##1}%
   \ifglshassymbol{##1}{% (rais) siehe `texdoc glossaries-user'.
     \glossentrysymbol{##1}%
   }{%
     \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}% (rais) gekürzt
   } &
   \glsentryuseri{##1} &
   \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription & ##2\tabularnewline
 }%
 \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{% (rais) siehe auch `texdoc glossaries-user', speziell ``Creating a completely new style''
    \glossentry{##2}{##3}% (rais) siehe oben.
 }%
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\relax}
}
\makeglossaries
\input{versuch.tex}
%\loadglsentries{versuch.tex}


\usepackage{makeidx}              % Sachregister
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}             % Quelltexte
\usepackage{listingsutf8}         % Quelltexte in UTF8
\usepackage[hang,font={sf,footnotesize},labelfont={footnotesize,bf}]{caption} % Beschriftungen
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}       % Schrift Helvetia laden
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}    % Absolute Textpositionen (für Deckblatt)
\usepackage{calc}                 % Berechnung von Positionen
\usepackage{blindtext}            % Blindtexte
\usepackage[bottom=30mm,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm]{geometry} % Ränder ändern
\usepackage{scrhack}              % tocbasic Warnung entfernen
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}          % Korrekte Verlinkung von Floats
\usepackage{tabularx}             % Spezielle Tabellen
%\usepackage{ltablex}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
%\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{C{#1}}

%\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
  isbn=false,                     % ISBN nicht anzeigen, gleiches geht mit nahezu allen anderen Feldern
  sortlocale=\hsmasortlocale,     % Sortierung der Einträge für Deutsch
                                  %      de_DE: für Deutsch
                                  %      en_US: für Englisch
  autocite=inline,                % regelt Aussehen für \autocite
                                  %      inline: Zitat in Klammern (\parancite)
                                  %      footnote: Zitat in Fußnoten (\footcite)
                                  %      plain: Zitat direkt ohne Klammern (\cite)
  style=alphabetic,                   % Legt den Stil für die Zitate fest
                                  %      ieee: Zitate als Zahlen [1]
                                  %      alphabetic: Zitate als Kürzel und Jahr [Ein05]
                                  %      authoryear: Zitate Author und Jahr [Einstein (1905)]
  hyperref=true,                  % Hyperlinks für Zitate
  firstinits=true                % Vornamen abkürzen (Maier, M. anstatt Maier, Markus)?
                                  %      true: abkürzen
                                  %      false: nicht abkürzen
]{biblatex}                       % Literaturverwaltung mit BibLaTeX
\usepackage{rotating}             % Seiten drehen
\usepackage{harveyballs}          % Harveyballs
\usepackage{chngcntr}             % Counter (Zähler) ändern können - für Fußnotennummern


% Einstellungen zu den Fußnoten
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{9}{10}\selectfont} % Größe der Fußnoten
\setlength{\footnotesep}{8pt} % Abstand zwischen den Fußnoten

% Kommentieren Sie diese Zeile ein, wenn Sie eine "durchlaufende" Nummerierung bei den
% Fußnoten wünschen, d.h. wenn die Fußnoten nicht bei jedem Kapitel wieder bei 1
% beginnen sollen.
%\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{1em}      % Abstand zwischen den Literaturangaben
\setlength{\bibhang}{2em}         % Einzug nach jeweils erster Zeile

% Trennung von URLs im Literaturverzeichnis (große Werte [> 10000] verhindern die Trennung)
\defcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{10} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Zahl
\defcounter{biburlucpenalty}{500} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Großbuchstaben
\defcounter{biburllcpenalty}{500} % Strafe für Trennung in URL nach Kleinbuchstaben

% Farben definieren
\definecolor{linkblue}{RGB}{0, 0, 100}
\definecolor{linkblack}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{comment}{RGB}{63, 127, 95}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{14, 144, 102}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,168}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{128,0,0}
\definecolor{javadoccomment}{RGB}{0,0,240}

% Einstellungen für das Hyperlink-Paket
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,      % Farbige links verwenden
%    allcolors=linkblue,
    linktoc=all,          % Links im Inhaltsverzeichnis
    linkcolor=linkblack,  % Querverweise
    citecolor=linkblack,  % Literaturangaben
    filecolor=linkblack,  % Dateilinks
    urlcolor=linkblack    % URLs
}

%Java-Script spezifisch:
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.9,.9,.9}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.65, 0.12, 0.82}

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
  keywords={typeof, new, true, false, catch, function, return, null, catch, switch, var, if, in, while, do, else, case, break},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  ndkeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{darkgray}\bfseries,
  identifierstyle=\color{black},
  sensitive=false,
  comment=[l]{//},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\color{purple}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]"
}

% Einstellungen für Quelltexte
\lstset{
      language=JavaScript,
      extendedchars=true,
      xleftmargin=0.2cm,
      basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
      keywordstyle=\color{darkgreen},
      identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
      commentstyle=\color{comment},
      stringstyle=\color{darkred},
      tabsize=2,
      lineskip={2pt},
      columns=flexible,
      inputencoding=utf8,
      captionpos=b,
      breakautoindent=true,
      breakindent=2em,
      breaklines=true,
      prebreak=,
      postbreak=,
      numbers=none,
      numberstyle=\tiny,
      showspaces=false,      % Keine Leerzeichensymbole
      showtabs=false,        % Keine Tabsymbole
      showstringspaces=false,% Leerzeichen in Strings
      morecomment=[s][\color{javadoccomment}]{/**}{*/},
      literate={Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}2 {ü}{{\"u}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1
}

\urlstyle{same}

% Einstellungen für Überschriften
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \Large\chapapp~\thechapter   % Große Schrift
  \vspace{0.3cm}               % Abstand zum Titel des Kapitels
}

% Abstände für die Überschriften setzen
\renewcommand{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{2.6cm}}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{1.5cm}}

% Vertikale Abstände für die Überschriften etwas verkleinern
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.25\baselineskip]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.15\baselineskip]{subsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=-1.8\baselineskip,
  afterskip=0.15\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

% In der Kopfzeile nur die kurze Kapitelbezeichnung (ohne Kapitel davor)
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}

% Einstellungen für Schriftarten
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\sffamily\bfseries\small}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\small}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\footnotesize}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\LARGE\selectfont\bfseries}

% Wichtige Abstände
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}  % 2mm Abstand zwischen zwei Absätzen
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}  % Absätze nicht einziehen
\clubpenalty = 10000         % Keine "Schusterjungen"
\widowpenalty = 10000        % Keine "Hurenkinder"
\displaywidowpenalty = 10000 % Keine "Hurenkinder"
                             % Siehe: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurenkind_und_Schusterjunge

% Index erzeugen
\makeindex

% Einfacher Font-Wechsel über dieses Makro
\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{
\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

% Eigenes Makro für Bilder. Das label (für \ref) ist dann einfach
% der Name der Bilddatei
\newcommand{\bild}[3]{
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}
  \caption{#3}
  \label{#1}
\end{figure}}

% Wo liegt Sourcecode?
\newcommand{\srcloc}{src/}

% Wo sind die Bilder?
\graphicspath{{bilder/}}

% Makros für typographisch korrekte Abkürzungen
\newcommand{\zb}[0]{z.\,B.}
\newcommand{\dahe}[0]{d.\,h.}
\newcommand{\ua}[0]{u.\,a.}

% Flags für Veröffentlichung und Sperrvermerk
\newboolean{hsmapublizieren}
\newboolean{hsmasperrvermerk}

% Tabellenzellen mit mehreren Zeilen
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{b}{l}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.3\hsize}l}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth\relax}X}

% Checklisten mit zwei Ebenen
\newlist{checklist}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[checklist]{label=$\square$}
```

Comment: There is a lot of custom code and a lot of files we don't have access to. You will have to do some trouble shooting yourself, by reducing the complexity of your document. Start by looking at the actual log file, perhaps?

Comment: Did you open the pdf externally while compiling? Then it fails in my environment. // To localize the sources of trouble I suggest to follow this systematic process: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 . It converges exponentially, as you will see.

Comment: all you  have have shown is some tex code you have not shown has an error logged  in `Refer to 'preambel.log' and/or above output for details` which you have not shown.

Comment: I wasn't able to post the preambel.log, because it was too long.
Couldn't find the problem, so I set the file up again.
Copied most of the codes, but this time it didn't fail...
But at least it works now.