# Table of contents giving "Undefined control sequence" error

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, undefined

The following code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, pdftex]{report}

% ==================================================================================
%  Configuración habitual
% ==================================================================================

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{framed}

% ==================================================================================
%  Símbolos matemáticos
% ==================================================================================



\def\N{\ensuremath{\mathbb{N}}}
\def\Z{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}}}
\def\Q{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Q}}}
\def\R{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}
\def\C{\ensuremath{\mathbb{C}}}


% 


\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts}





% ==================================================================================
% Tipos
% ==================================================================================



\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

% ==================================================================================
%  Colores
% ==================================================================================

\usepackage[ dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{azulUCA}{cmyk}{1.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.51}
\definecolor{naranjaUCA}{cmyk}{0.00, 0.51, 1.00, 0.00}
\definecolor{grisUCA}{cmyk}{0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.65}

% ==================================================================================
%  Diseño del documento
% ==================================================================================


% Chapter

\usepackage[left=1.2in,right=1.2in,top=1in,bottom=1in,includefoot,heightrounded]{geometry}


\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}


\newpagestyle{mine}{%
\headrule
\sethead{}{}{\itshape\chaptertitle}
\setfoot{}{}{\bfseries\thepage}}%

\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\setfoot{}{}{\bfseries\thepage}}%


\pagestyle{mine}



\usepackage[palatino]{quotchap}

\colorlet{chaptergrey}{Maroon}  % color for chapter number

\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}[{\color{Maroon}\titlerule[0.8pt]}]



\parindent 0pt



\usepackage{draftwatermark}

% ==================================================================================
%  Entornos Problema y Solución
% ==================================================================================



\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{definition}{
              boxrule=0pt,
              boxsep=0pt,
              colback={White!90!Cerulean},
              enhanced jigsaw, 
              borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{Cerulean},
              sharp corners,
              before skip=10pt,
              after skip=10pt,
              breakable,
     }
     
\newtcolorbox{theorem}{ boxrule=0pt,
              boxsep=0pt,
              colback={White!90!Dandelion},
              enhanced jigsaw, 
              borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{Dandelion},
              sharp corners,
              before skip=10pt,
              after skip=10pt,
              breakable,}
     
\newtcolorbox{lemma}{ boxrule=0pt,
              boxsep=0pt,
              colback={White!90!LimeGreen},
              enhanced jigsaw, 
              borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{LimeGreen},
              sharp corners,
              before skip=10pt,
              after skip=10pt,
              breakable,}     


\newtcolorbox{example}{
        boxrule=0pt,
          boxsep=0pt,
          blanker,
          borderline west={1pt}{0pt}{Black},
          sharp corners,
          before skip=10pt,
          after skip=10pt,
          left=12pt,
          right=12pt,
          breakable,
        }

\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}{Definición}[]
\newtheorem*{ej}{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem*{nt}{Nota}

\newenvironment{teorema}[1][]{
    \begin{theorem}
    \begin{thm}[#1]
    }{
    \end{thm}
    \end{theorem}
    }

\newenvironment{lema}[1][]{
    \begin{lemma}
    \begin{lem}[#1]
    }{
    \end{lem}
    \end{lemma}
    }    

\newenvironment{definicion}{
    \begin{definition}
    \begin{defn}
    }{
    \end{defn}
    \end{definition}
    }

\newenvironment{ejemplo}{
    
    \begin{example}
    \begin{ej}
}{




\end{ej}
\end{example}
}

\newenvironment{nota}{
    
    \begin{example}
    \begin{nt}
}{




\end{nt}
\end{example}
}

% ==================================================================================
%  Documento
% ==================================================================================







\title{Ecuaciones Diferenciales}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{127,0,0}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{169,121,69}
\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{{\color{myyellow}\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt} \hspace{10pt}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addtocontents{toc}%
                                   {%
                                       {\protect\parbox{3.5em}{\hfill\Huge\color{myred}\bfseries\thepage}}%
                                         \protect\hspace*{.5em}
                                        \protect\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-4em\relax}{%
                                           \protect\begin{leftbar}
                                              {\scshape\small\chaptername~\thechapter}\\\sffamily#1%
                                           \protect\end{leftbar}}\par\noindent
                                    }%
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\makeatother


\begin{center}




\vspace*{1cm}

\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{logouca (1).jpg} 

\vspace*{3cm}
\begin{Large}
Resumen
\end{Large}

\vspace*{0.3in}
\textbf{\huge \bigskip Ecuaciones Diferenciales I} % Aquí el título de su trabajo 
% Si el título del trabajo supera un párrafo añadir el comando \bigskip antes del título para que no se solapen dichos párrafos

\thispagestyle{empty} % Impide que se incluya número de página en la portada
 % Comienza a incluir números de página a partir de aquí % En números romanos



\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{page}{1}
```

is giving me the error

```
\@mkboth ->\ttl@savemark 
                         \@gobbletwo 
l.306 \tableofcontents
                      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

But it compiles and shows the table of contents, so it seems to be only a technical issue.

When I delete the line `\usepackage[palatino]{quotchap}` the problem disappears so I think it's a problem with that package?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately your code can't compile ... // If it's too long, why don't you try localizing the problem(s) systematically, like described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 ? This process converges quickly ...

Comment: `\ttl@...` commands are from the `titletoc`  and `titlesec` packages

Comment: And what is the problem with titletoc/sec?