# pdf plots/figures have weird artifacts

Tags: pdf, compiling, bugs

So I used to use svg-files for my plots, but compiling with too many figures took way too long, so I switched to pdf-figures, which works way better in that aspect. I did **not** convert the svg files to pdf, I saved the plots from matplotlib directly into pdf files.

But now I get weird artifacts of some sorts in a few of my plots, like for example the little box in the bottom left corner:

**[Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qgO9uSEYk1Gq7CwjlYo6m1MNNGP_xkVK/view?usp=drive_link) (opened in adobe):**
[image: Original Plot]

**Screenshot of compiled figure:**
[image: Screenshot of compiled figure]

For some reason, there is a little box in the bottom left corner of the compiled figure.

This is the corresponding tex code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/Costs_Validation_linearreg_neg.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
```

If anyone knows what this could be about, please let me know!

([Dropbox link for pdf file)](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pd3lcntyfbolozfox79jz/Costs_Validation_linearreg_neg.pdf?rlkey=c5var3bdeqdfvbzw7ynqneldg&dl=0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Welcome! How did you transform the SVG to PDF? Can you see the little box in a PDF viewer (try several)? Can you provide a (small) example SVG & PDF files that show the problem?

Comment: I fear without access to your .svg etc. my telepathic skill won‘t do this time …

Comment: @Rmano I saved it directly from the matplotlib to a pdf file and when I open the file with adobe it looks like it should, but when I open it with firefox it shows the weird box. How can I link the file here?

Comment: @Rmano Ok, I linked the original pdf above the image

Comment: Behind the scenes, the svg package uses inkscape to convert the svg file to pdf. You could manually do this and use the resulting pdf file in your document.

Comment: Can you share your svg and pdf in a way which does not require a google account?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I added a dropbox link, hope that works

Comment: @maxxel_ Thanks! I can't reproduce the artefact in a compiled document: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6hPx.png Can you a) share your compiled document? b) test with different pdf viewers?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok, so it is pretty weird... I just compiled the latex file and when it opens the whole document in a new tab, it looks like in the preview with the artifact: [Full document](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ql5iittzy3ktluvbk87jf/full_doc.png?rlkey=zlq6f5pqrnfrc8vzg6px4ul87&dl=0)

But when I saved just the single page and opened it with the same browser, the artifact is gone: [Single page document](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zwqq18bfogc9k63clmypr/single_page.png?rlkey=kltgrcr3ahcrs57oabg375lnn&dl=0)

Answer (score 3):

To clarify for the down-voter:

- a solution (answer) in this case can't be some Latex-code
- it has to be a root-cause analysis
- this one lays-out the road towards the handful of root causes, which probably are only valid in the TO's environment.

If you can do better, please do so ;-)

---

Let's try another summary, though from the comments the TO probably made a conclusion, that can be right, or can be wrong.

Kindly check the last item, "**Suggested tests**", below.

---

#### Trials

###### > Compile

- me: Texmaker, pdflatex, MikTex
- TO: Overleaf, unknown latex-compiler

###### > Artifacts seen?

- me: none (Acrobat Reader, Firefox)
- TO: with FireFox, depending on conditions (see e.g. [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694351/pdf-plots-figures-have-weird-artifacts/694523#comment1723954_694351))

*(So, FF per se can't be the problem, as it can both show AND not-show the artifact, depending on where it's used. Other unmentioned differences must be the root-cause(s).)*

###### > Opening pdf or svg from dropbox (see above)

- me: no artifacts visible

#### Inspecting the svg-file

Both with `inkscape` and `Notepad++ (Editor)` many SVG-paths are evident, as it should, for:

- data points, linear fit, triangular areas etc.
- frames and grids
- characters (letters, numers, punctuation ...)

From probing some, not all, one SV-path stands out:

```
<path id="ArialMT-2e" d="M 581 0 
L 581 641 
L 1222 641 
L 1222 0 
L 581 0 
z
" transform="scale(0.015625)"/>
...
```

which renders as a nice square using e.g. [this online svg-path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) and is harder to catch with inkscape:

[image: svg-path]

[image: inkscape]

This one looks quite similar to the troublemaker, the TO reported several times here.

#### Can this be the trouble maker?

May be. It's evident from `Notepad++` that aboves definition `id="ArialMT-2e"`is referenced a number of times.

All that's required to turn this into a fluctuating (= depending on circumstances, reported by the TO) artifact is some kind of unintended interpretation of the SVG-elements, e.g. by:

- the LaTeX compiler used, including its compile options
- mis-treating one of the SVG-XML-structures
- browser pecularities, including Add-Ons used/not-used
- etc.

[image: notepad++]

---

### Suggested tests

To localize variation (or noise in robustness-speak) we must vary the noise-source, which is the SVG-file in this case.

So the TO could create a number of dedicated SVG-files, and repeat his/her compile process, and check for occurance of this artifact.

There are a number of ways to do this. The most practical one may be the **progressing 50:50-strategy**, as I [lined out here in a Latex-context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159), and which converges fast/exponentially:

- guided by the XML-structure of the SVG-file split it roughly into half (which is meant more as an idea, less as a precise measurement) :
- one half containing these pathes, the other taking the others, while preserving the structural metadata and other parts needed for file integrity (i.e. still renders graphics)
- check, which one still creates the artifact
- discard the non-artifact-half
- repeat until you can localize the trouble making element or path

When neither half seems to create an artifact anymore, go one step back and consider a different split, until you definately reached an end.

*BTW: This is easy to do, and lengthy to describe in words ...*

This should quickly lead to one or a few XML-parts, which are worth for further consideration. At this point, you can even try generating SVG-variants/contents, where you can switch the artifact on and off as you want: a kind of verification of the root cause(s).

A different route may be to discard intentionally all, half or many of the parts referencing `id="ArialMT-2e"`.

THE END

#### P.S.

A shortcut or pre-test may be to change the path of said square into a different shape, e.g. by adding a distinctive 5th point. After compile the TO should see the square-artifact replaced by this new shape, IF that's the trouble maker.

Then, further localization as described above.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two compiles with classes `article` and `standalone` with the pdf from your dropbox: no box shown, compiling with `pdflatex`.

Once again, you should post compilable code, not just snippets:

- now it seems the box might be an artifact from your preamble etc.
- or from your Latex installation
- etc.

[image: article and standalone]

Screenshots taken from `Acrobat Reader 2023`; same with `FireFox`.

#### article

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Costs_Validation_linearreg_neg.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

#### standalone

For some reason tikz was needed to compile ...

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics%[width=\textwidth]
    {Costs_Validation_linearreg_neg.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, so I've tried both in a blank project and I still get the same [artifact](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/d3d29s8w0k1duz72b55qu/blank_test.png?rlkey=3lsmxnqzq9j162jbb1jn4pq1e&dl=0), it probably has something to do with firefox, since it looks fine in adobe...

Comment: Hmm, so it may be related to Overleaf? Did you try to view the generated pdf externally, e.g. in Acrobat or a browser? // Can you try a different compiler, like Lualatex etc.?

Comment: yes, I tried both and the artifact shows in firefox, but not in adobe. Is there something I can try to change in the overleaf settings?

Comment: Ok. Which FF version do you use? Browsers do different things differently: did you try other ones? Can you also upload the pdf you just mentioned in your comments (Acro ok, FF not)?

Comment: Can you also please upload the svg you used here? It may hold both more information and chances to introduce variations, like reducing the dataset.

Comment: FF is up-to-date, but I just tried overleaf in edge and it works there. I think it's just a weird quirk of FF. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/gsevwf1zvngp4luexlanx/Costs_Validation_linearreg_neg.svg?rlkey=hfb8a0nm7yut5mlrr8dvdolm8&dl=0) is the svg file though.

Answer (score -1):

This is not necessary an answer, but more an educated guess/ motivation/suggestion of what might be happening/what could be done based upon the comments and answers by @MS-SPO.
Investigating the original matplotlib pdf output, for example at hexcode `00012600`  to `000126C4` one can find:

```
obj.<< /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /CFEKEO+ArialMT
/Flags 32./FontBBox [ -665 -325 2000 1040 ] /Ascent 906
/Descent -212 /CapHeight 716 ./XHeight 519 /ItalicAngle 0
/StemV 0 /MaxWidth 1015 >>. endobj.14
```

which is expected to be there (otherwise one could not copy the text out of the pdf). However, the interesting part is the `FontBBox`. This denotes a (normally invisible) bounding box for text. The interesting fact is that there are multiple of those `FontBBox` defined within the document with exactly the same parameters `[ -665 -325 2000 1040 ]`. If during the conversion from `pdf` to `svg` one includes the font as font and not as path, I am not sure how these `FontBBox` are handled. If one does a rough calculation and the scale of your plot (`1e6`), the sometimes visible rectangles around the starting point of your data could be from a misinterpretation of the to svg converted`FontBBox` as a path.
Why this occurs only if you compile a certain way, use a certain viewer etc. cannot be clarified unless one could analyze the relevant source code of all components involved (which is impossible due to the closed nature of especially Adobe Products). My educated guess from my experience: The LaTeX compilation is different for a one-page document than if one has multiple pages (due to linking, references etc.). I assume that in conjunction with the undefined `FontBBox` behavior introduced by the plot inclusion, this creates partially invalid pdfs which are not identical on a binary level. Some pdf viewer handle errors differently (ignoring invalid elements), but also if the errors exceed a certain amount, the pdf viewer might get overwhelmed, consequently the error handling will break and every invalid garbage will be rendered.

I had a similar, but yet very different issue once before: I included photographs containing meta data via `\includegraphics`. I verified the resulting pdf with several pdf viewers, including the commonly used browers; everything was displayed correctly. To make sure, I even removed (at least it seemed so) the rotation meta data information from the images to ensure that there is less chance of an artifact. However, after the publisher compiled, processed and published the document, in certain versions of Firefox the images would be rendered rotated by 90° (because sometimes Firefox was using the rotation provided with the image meta data instead of the one set by LaTeX during compilation). The Take-Home-Message: No matter how hard one tries, the weirdest bugs can occur in pdf no matter how careful one is. Sometimes manual post-processing of figures before including them into a pdf document is the only way to mitigate the risk, but does not protect completely from such artifacts. 
From this rotation bug, my pragmatical recommendation would be (if possible):

1. Open your original matplotlib output pdf with Inkscape
2. Try to select elements around the area where the box sometimes occurs (it might be that these boxes are invisible/hidden, but usually they can be selected and deleted). If you delete the selection and none of the important information is gone, it might be that you found and eliminated a ghost element which might be able to cause issues.
3. Save the image as pdf.

If you can export raw data from your data analysis tool and are willing to use another plotting tool: A solution might be to use `pgfplots` to create the plots directly in LaTeX, which in my experience is more reliable regarding fonts and rendering artifacts (and makes the whole document more visually cohesive since it uses all the LaTeX settings like correct spacing etc.).