How to embed PDF as an image in latex?
I have previously inserted floated images in .eps format like this:

But then to improve the image quality, i decided to insert images in .pdf format but as a result, i am getting the following output
How to resolve this?  I am using this code:
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
  \subfloat[\textrm{Gold-Kasami}]{\label{fig:Fig1} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{goldkasamipdf.pdf}}
  \subfloat[\textrm{Chaotic-Kasami}]{\label{fig:Fig2} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{chaotickasamipdf.pdf}}\\
  \subfloat[\textrm{Gold-Chaotic}]{\label{fig:Fig3} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{goldchaoticpdf.pdf}}
  \subfloat[\textrm{Barker-Kasami}]{\label{fig:Fig4} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{barkerkasamipdf.pdf}}\\
  \subfloat[\textrm{Barker-Chaotic}]{\label{fig:Fig5} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{barkerchaoticpdf.pdf}}
  \subfloat[\textrm{Barker-Gold }]{\label{fig:Fig6} \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{barkergoldpdf.pdf}}\\

\caption{cross-correlation ($\eta$) of Kronecker Product based Phase coded signals in different configurations}
\label{fig:combinedFigures}
\vspace{-0.2cm}
\end{figure}


How exactly did you make the PDF versions? You can always check the dimentions of the image (as seen by LaTeX) by using \fbox{\includegraphics....}, seem to me what those PDFs are not cropped. Hence why I ask how exactly the PDFs are made.

Can you show the first few lines of your .log file so we can see which engine you use to compile your document?

I used overleaf. These images are saved as pdf from the software 'MATLAB'

Note that pdf is not necessarily better quality than eps. In essence it is the same format, so it can be the same quality - maybe you would need to adjust the export settings from Matlab for the eps if it doesn't look good as it is.

My guess is that MATLAB (like many other programmes) does not properly crop the PDFs when they may them, and thus leave a lot of white space. On a normal LaTeX installation one can run pdfcrop on each PDF to generate file-crop.pdf then then one can use that. Not sure if pdfcrop is available as a tool on OverLeaf.

See e.g. here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694523/245790 and here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701698/245790 .
