# use of chemfig package - conflict with graphicx package

Tags: graphics, chemfig

I am using the following code, which works well:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\begin{document}
\section{Tetracene} 
\vspace{2cm}
\chemname[2ex]{\chemfig{*6(1?-2-3*6(-4-5*6(-6-7*6(-8-9-10-11-\phantom{12})-12-13-\phantom{14})-14-15-\phantom{16})-16-17-18?)}}{Tetracene}
\end{document}
```

When I try to use this in my thesis chapter, the bonds are not drawn: all numbers appear on top of each other.

---

Edit: The chemfig package and the graphicx package are conflicting with each other - below the code that does not work:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% packages

% Integration of jpeg graphics
\usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}
% Document images path
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
% drawing molecules
\usepackage{chemfig}
%% end packages

\begin{document}
\section{Tetracene}
\vspace{2cm}
\chemfig{**6(10?-15-11**6(-16-12**6(-17-13**6(-18-14-9-4-\phantom{8})-8-3-\phantom{7})-7-2-\phantom{16})-6-1-5?)}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: If this code works well, please provide an example that does not work. We do not know your document, the packages you use etc. It might be an idea to copy the entire thing to a new document and then start removing things to see if they are relevant.

Comment: The whole document is very long...It is not clear to me which packages might conflict. For sure \chemfig is loaded, because I would have an error if not, such as "provide a definition of \chemfig ".

Comment: To localize your problem(s), kindly follow this systematic process, which is quick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159 . Should it remain unsolved you probably can post a better non-working code example, which isn‘t too long.

Comment: @None Are you sure the `dvips` is a good idea? In the best case it is unnecessary, in the worst case it will cause problems if you compile your document via another route.

Comment: No-one should be using the `dvips` option for `graphicx` these days. It can detect that automatically (I tihnk it is only if you are one of the few that is using `dvipdfm` that a driver is needed). Forcing `dvips` under say pdflatex, may cause strange issues.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers!  I could simply remove the \usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}. I am using the template of someone else and building on top what I need - so I am not sure why there was the need to force the conversion to a specific format (as far as I understood what it does!)

Answer (score 1):

this code worked fine for me (Texlive 2023)

What is your version of TEX?

ChemFig has had a lot of changes recently, and if you are using an older version of ChemFig, problems can occur.

[image]

You can use "?[name]" to join the rings instead of \phantom

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\begin{document}
    \section{Tetracene} 
    \vspace{2cm}
    \chemname[2ex]{\chemfig{*6(1?[a]-2-3*6(-4-5*6(-6-7*6(-8-9-10-11?[d])-12?[d]-13?[c])-14?[c]-15?[b])-16?[b]-17-18?[a])}}{Tetracene}
\end{document}
```

To avoid problems with the code below, remove the "dvips" option. You are compiling with Pdflatex, you don't need dvips.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% packages

% Integration of jpeg graphics
\usepackage[dvips,final]{graphicx}
% Document images path
\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}
% drawing molecules
\usepackage{chemfig}
%% end packages

\begin{document}
\section{Tetracene}
\vspace{2cm}
\chemfig{**6(10?-15-11**6(-16-12**6(-17-13**6(-18-14-9-4-\phantom{8})-8-3-\phantom{7})-7-2-\phantom{16})-6-1-5?)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi CrocoDuck,

I have an overleaf account, and the compiler is pdfLateX 2022. 
The code you proposed also works fine but even simple molecules like \chemfig{H-H} are not printing the bond...

Comment: I don't use overleaf... Take a test, change \documentclass to "article". Not all latex packages work well on all document classes.

Comment: CrocoDuck : \documentclass{article} works well - I followed the idea of conflicting packages and edited my question. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer, now your code works.

Comment: Thank you @CrocoDuck