# How to make the formatting of CV consistent?

Tags: templates

The formatting of my CV was fine until I opened the file yesterday and found that my skills section and part of my education section is not aligned properly. As well as the being dashes instead of bullet points. I have made several unsuccessful attempts to fix these errors, but have had no success.

Can you help me to resolve this issue.

A screenshot of my CV can be seen below.

A minimal example of the .sty file for my CV can be seen below.

```
\titleformat{\section}{\color{highlight} \scshape \raggedright \large}{}{0em}{}[\vspace{-0.75em}\hrulefill]
% SUBSECTION FORMATTING
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0em}{0em}{0em}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries}{}{0em}{}[]

% BOLD COMMAND
\newcommand{\skills}[1]{ {\bfseries #1}}

% SUBTEXT
\newcommand{\subtext}[1]{\textit{#1}\par\vspace{-.75em}}

% tighter spacing than itemize
\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft,left=0pt..1em}
\newenvironment{zitemize}{
\begin{itemize} \itemsep 0pt \parskip 0pt \parsep 1pt}
{\end{itemize}\vspace{-.5em}}

% NO PAGE NUMBER
\pagenumbering{gobble}

% SUBFILES IMPORTING
\RequirePackage{standalone}

% FOR TEMPLATE FILLER
\RequirePackage[english]{babel}
%\RequirePackage{blindtext}% Filler Text
```

A minimal example of my resume.tex file can be seen below.

```
\def\gitlab{RasaiStewart} % gitlab username
\def\role{Graduate of Computer Science (AI)} % JOB TITLE

\input{_header}
\begin{document}

\section{Personal Statement}
\input{sections/Personal Statement}

\section{Relevant Experience}
\input{sections/experience}

\section{Education}
\input{sections/education}

\section{Skills}
\input{sections/skills}
%section{Volunteer Work}
%\input{sections/Volunteer Work}

%\section{Languages}
%\input{sections/languages.tex}

% make a newpage wherever it is a clean break
% \newpage
%\section{Coursework projects}
%\input{sections/Coursework projects}

\section{Personal projects}
\input{sections/Personal Projects}% corrected spelling of input DJC

%\section{Interests}
%\input{sections/Certifications.tex}

\section{Awards}
\input{sections/Awards.tex}

\section{Courses}
\input{sections/Courses.tex}

%\section{Activities}
%\input{sections/activities}

%\section{Interests}
%\input{sections/Interests}

%\section{references}
%\input{sections/references}

\end{document}
```

The output can be seen below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have a nested itemize? Also, in general it is better to show a minimal example here on this site, not links to other sites.

Comment: @mickep I was adding a minimal example, but put a link to another website by mistake.

Comment: @RasaiStewart, looks like your screenshot was not included: please insert it again. Also, it looks like you post two codes. While the .sty may or may not be ok, the document should start with \documentclass. Please add what‘s missing. Using ~~~ will help you to end the .sty and to stat the .tex file. Thank you

Comment: @mickep The .sty file in the template I used to create my CV did not start with \documentclass, but I am still able to compile it.

Comment: @RasaiStewart, unfortunately your posted code can't be minimal, as it woll not/can't compile. Please try yourself on a fresh file in a fresh directory. Usually such questions will be closed very soon, unless you provide substantial input.

Comment: @RasaiStewart, what happened between the last time, your CV was fine and yesterday, when it no longer was? Did you change something? Did your Latex plattform change one way ot the other?

Comment: The Latex platform I use is Overleaf. I have not made anychanges to my CV. I do not see any changes in Overleaf between the last time my CV was fine and now.

Comment: I may have changed the TEX live version from 2021 (Legacy) or 2022 to 2023.

Comment: @RasaiStewart, fine, at least that‘s something to follow and verify. You may want to create some copies to apply this strategy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159 . It usually brings you very quickly to that part(s) of your code, which cause trouble. At least, once narrowed down, you can investigate and introduce intentionally changes with greater focus.