# Can't compile entire book in LyX – "Environment lyxlist undefined"

Tags: lyx, compiling

I can no longer compile my entire book in LyX and I don't understand the mistake as it is presented. Apparently, something is not correctly defined in one of my chapters (child documents).

It gives me this as an error output:

> LaTeX Error: Environment lyxlist undefined.

and for the separate lines:

> \begin{minipage} on input line xxx ended by \end{lyxlist}.

And then it gives me three separate lines. When I let them present to me in the original file, it's plainly formatted standard text, however.

In the description it reads as:

> \begin{lyxlist}
> {=longestlabel}
> Your command was ignored.
> Type  I    to replace it with another command,
> or    to continue without it.

It's however possible, to compile the child document separately. I don't know how to solve this and am gladly hoping for further advice from your side!

Best!

EDIT: I now know that the problem is due to an inability to compile the minipages that I can compile in the child documents in the main document. I still don't know how to properly fix it as I tried several approaches by now. Any help?

Comment: If no one responds here, I suggest you joint the lyx-users mailing list and ask there.

Comment: Ah, interesting, where can I find that mailing list?

Comment: Here: https://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2

Comment: Also if possible it would be much easier to help if you send a minimal example. In this case, a minimal example would consist of multiple files (i.e., the master and children).

Comment: Copy everything over to a new project.  Delete all other child documents and their references from the main document.  Delete everything from this child document other than the offending environment.  Can you get it down to 40 lines total that still has this error?

Comment: @Suza, try to narrow down the problem(s). First, at least your last changes may be relevant. Second, apply the 50:50 strategy described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651156/how-to-declutter-your-main-tex/651159#651159 ... it converges very fast, i.e. leads you more or less by itself to your trouble makers.