# Error during Overleaf compiling

Tags: compilation-error

I have never had this mistake during file compiling. Can anyone tell me why could it appear, please?
Why missing $ inserted when I write \chapter{Simulation Setup}?

[image]

Comment: We don't know what you have in your code, it would be more helpful if you share the code. Also, Overleaf sometimes says  where the missing $ could be, it's srolling down, under in the 'Missing $ inserted' warning.

Comment: ^ Before you share your code, please first take some time to try to isolate which *part* of your code contains the error. For example, you could try commenting out your code one paragraph at a time to find the paragraph that contains the error. Please don't just share *all* of your code.

Comment: Welcome! Never post pictures of code or errors. Instead, copy-paste errors and code into your post. Not only does this help others trying to help you, it is essential for accessibility and search. Your question is currently unreadable by users who depend on screen readers.

Comment: do you use some package or code that redefines \section? What is one the lines before?

Comment: The only thing I'm able to tell is that your error occurs on the first line of the file you've shown.  Something has gone wrong before that point.  In the file where you `\input` (or `\include`) the file `...n Setup.tex`, replace that `\input` with `\section{Simulation Setup}` and delete everything afterward except for the `\end{document}`.  Then start deleting everything before the `\section` command until you isolate what is causing the error.

Comment: To narrow dow your error, you can apply this strategy: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 . Many times that's all you need to understand, where the error comes from. // Should the error prevail, to convert the isolated part into a MWE, you may want to follow these practical steps: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that/10137#10137