# "Undefined control sequence. Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?." - LaTex error for 2 Sierpinski traingles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw two Sierpinski triangles that touch on a vertix.
My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  main tri/.style={isosceles triangle, isosceles triangle apex angle=60, draw, anchor=apex, inner sep=0},
  node distance=0mm,
  minimum height=6cm
]

% Define recursive macro to create the Sierpinski triangle pattern
\newcommand\createsierpinski[3]{
  \ifnum#3>0
    % Calculate size for the smaller triangles
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newsize}{#1/2}
    % Calculate the position for the next set of triangles
    \path #2;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newya}{\y-0.25*#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newyb}{\y-0.75*#1}
    % Draw the three smaller triangles
    \createsierpinski{\newsize}{([yshift=-0.25*#1]#2)}{#3-1}
    \createsierpinski{\newsize}{([yshift=-0.25*#1]#2.east)}{#3-1}
    \createsierpinski{\newsize}{([yshift=-0.75*#1]#2.east)}{#3-1}
  \fi
}

% First Sierpinski triangle
\node[main tri] (A) {};
\createsierpinski{6cm}{A}{4}

% Second Sierpinski triangle (rotated to touch at the tip)
\node[main tri, rotate=180] (B) at (A.apex) {};
\createsierpinski{6cm}{B}{4}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your code so that it is compilable for people who don't have your main file?

Comment: Hard to answer this since we don't know what packages/libraries you're using. At least `tikz` and `shapes.geometric`. What else? what is `\y`? Just guessing, but do you want `\path (#2);`? Also, you may want to check out the library `lindenmayersystems`, which can probably automate this for you.

Comment: You can't say `\ifnum3-1>0`, you need to parse the calculation first using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` for example.

Comment: Welcome. // To localize your problem(s) quickly I suggest to apply the 50:50 strategy as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790

Comment: Sorry, my telekinetic skill failed to open your main.tex to have a look ...

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but this should work:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    main tri/.style={
        isosceles triangle, 
        isosceles triangle apex angle=60, 
        draw, 
        anchor=apex, 
        inner sep=0pt
    },
    node distance=0mm,
    minimum height=6cm,
]

% Define recursive macro to create the Sierpinski triangle pattern
\newcommand\createsierpinski[4][]{
  \ifnum#4>0
    % Calculate size for the smaller triangles
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\newsize}{#2/2}
    \node[main tri, #1, anchor=apex, minimum height={\newsize}] 
        (#3-1) at (#3.apex) {};
    \node[main tri, #1, anchor=right corner, minimum height={\newsize}] 
        (#3-2) at (#3.right corner) {};
    \node[main tri, #1, anchor=left corner, minimum height={\newsize}] 
        (#3-3) at (#3.left corner) {};
    % Draw the three smaller triangles
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\newi}{#4-1}
    \begin{scope}
        \createsierpinski[#1]{\newsize}{#3-1}{\newi}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \createsierpinski[#1]{\newsize}{#3-2}{\newi}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \createsierpinski[#1]{\newsize}{#3-3}{\newi}
    \end{scope}
  \fi
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{1}

% First Sierpinski triangle
\node[main tri] (A) {};
\createsierpinski{6cm}{A}{4}

% Second Sierpinski triangle (rotated to touch at the tip)
\node[main tri, rotate=180] (B) at (A.apex) {};
\createsierpinski[rotate=180]{6cm}{B}{4}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Your code has some problems and some other shortcomings.

1. With `\path #2;` and `A` given to the second argument, you'll get `\path A;` which is not valid Ti*k*Z syntax and is the reason for the "missing semicolon" error. You need to use parenthesis here and remove them in the nested `\createsierpinski` commands.
2. If you give `[yshift=-0.25*#1]#2` as second argument to the command, you will also get, at some point, invalid syntax. But there is actually no need for `yshift` as you can simply use the anchors of the node shape for positioning.
3. You command defintion currently neither includes a `\draw` nor a `\node` command, hence there is no output.
4. You can't say `\ifnum3-1>0`, but you need to do the calculation beforhand because `\ifnum` can only compare integers. You can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to this end.
5. You need some scoping, because otherwise the first nested `\createsierpinski` will already end the recursion loop.
6. If you want to rotate things, you need to pass this transformation as option to every single `\createsierpinski` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using `lindenmayersystems` (chapter 57 in the [PGF manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[l-system={step=.5pt, order=8, angle=60}, rotate=-30]
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski triangle}{
    \symbol{X}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \symbol{Y}{\pgflsystemdrawforward}
    \rule{X -> Y-X-Y}
    \rule{Y -> X+Y+X}
  }
  \draw[red] (0,0) l-system[l-system={Sierpinski triangle, axiom=+++X, anchor=north east}]; 
  \draw[blue] (0,0) l-system[l-system={Sierpinski triangle, axiom=X, anchor=south west}]; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```