Error when drawing geometric rays in Tikz
I have made this code in Tikz, and it appears red in that section of the code, could someone help me on what I should change please?
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Dibujar los ejes
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[left] {};

    % Dibujar los vectores (ángulos)
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (3,3);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (3,2);

    % Etiquetas de los ángulos
    \node at (1.5, 0.3) {$30^\circ - 2x$};
    \node at (1.8, 2.3) {$x + 10^\circ$};

    % Dibujar los arcos de los ángulos
    \draw (0.7,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=30,radius=0.7];
    \draw (0.7,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=1.2];

    % Marcar el ángulo recto
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3);

\end{tikzpicture}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The problem probably occurs earlier in the code.  It is possible to reset the default colors, using \tikzset for example.

do you mean the output is red? or do you mean that your editor highlights part of your code red to indicate that's where the error is?

Please add a compilable test document.

please also tell us the actual error you get. all we can tell right now is that some code somewhere causes some error, which you probably already know ;).

Don't see any problem with your code snippet ... Usually you have to boil it down into an artificial short version, which

compiles (!)
still shows your problem

When embedded correctly:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    % Dibujar los ejes
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[below] {};
    \draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[left] {};
    
    % Dibujar los vectores (ángulos)
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (3,3);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (3,2);
    
    % Etiquetas de los ángulos
    \node at (1.5, 0.3) {$30^\circ - 2x$};
    \node at (1.8, 2.3) {$x + 10^\circ$};
    
    % Dibujar los arcos de los ángulos
    \draw (0.7,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=30,radius=0.7];
    \draw (0.7,0) arc[start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=1.2];
    
    % Marcar el ángulo recto
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (0.3,0.3);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}

... then this is the result:

Suggestion: have a look at the angle library from tikz.

From what I was seeing, the problem was because of the "->" symbol.

The code I posted compiles and is syntactically correct. But nobody can know your big document.

To localize your problems, beside checking the logfile, I suggest to apply the 50:50 method, as lined out e.g. here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/651159/245790 .
